# Why am I not getting Aztec hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

The hat is for getting 20 hats. I've 21, but it's been more than 2 days and I've still not gotten that hat.

Is this a bug or have I not fulfilled the criteria?

Answer (score 8):

You get the Aztec hat if you have 20 hats *on one site*. You have 18 hats on Stack Overflow, which means you don't get the Aztec hat.

Comment: oh! It's not been documented thanks!(or is it?)

Comment: @AmitJoki Hmm... I don't know whether it is documented or not. But I know this reason because it was the same in 2013, for a similar hat.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get 20 hats on one site. It looks like you have 18 or 19 on SO, but not 20. Get 20 hats on one site and you'll soon get the Aztec hat.

I am modeling the Aztec hat currently :)

Comment: Ok. Seems legit. Didn't read about this anywhere. Thanks